# Prefix for listing table

Tags: listings

For my thesis I need to create a list of source code (as a table) that has the same style as my other table of contents. For all of my source code examples I use `\lstinputlisting` in order to load it from a specific file.

The current display of items in my table is as following:
[image]

I need the format like in this example:
[image]

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\clearpage
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=first code example]
<some code here>
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=second code example]
<some code here>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

How do I add the prefix "Code" in front of the numbers, followed by a colon and finished by left aligning the whole line?

Edit: After including the solution that has been provided by @Tiuri I noticed a problem with too long captions that are distributed over multiple lines.

[image]

How can the caption text be aligned evenly, like in the first image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `\numberline` to put some text before every entry in the table of listings. In this example, I added "Code" to every entry:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\hspace{-1.5em}Code \oldnumberline{#1:}}
\lstlistoflistings
\endgroup

\clearpage
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=first code example]
<some code here>
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=second code example]
<some code here>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: Added a colon and shifted the captions to the left page border.

Comment: This helps me a lot, thank you. However, it doesn't solve another problem, that of too long captions. How should I proceed if I want the caption (that breaks over multiple lines) to be aligned evenly (also on the left hand side)? Also the numbering is not evenly aligned vertically.